# How to make random key value in JSON?

Tags: json

I want make random key value as per my `counter` variable. Suppose I have one incremental variable as per requirements. I want to pass that value as key name of my JSON.

```
[
  1 : {  "A" : "B" },
  2 : [ {"A1" : "B1"},{"A1" : "B1"}],
  5 : [ {"A2" : "B2"},{"A2" : "B2"}],
  8 : [ {"A2" : "B3"},{"A4" : "B4"}]
]
```

I just want to know is that possible to set key value of JSON like above `(1,2,5,8)` ? If yes than please let me know How ? Or any help regarding these ?

Comment: How is your JSON generated?

Comment: based on `key` I want access that array. like `obj[1], obj[2], obj[5]` .